# search for same string with different number in sqllite db

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I have a program that quickly translates some predefined sentences by searching them in a database.

A sample sentence would be:

`I like to eat 2 sandwitches every 3 days`

problem is that the database could contain the sentence:

`I like to eat 3 sandwitches every 3 days`

so the query wont find it. The problems i am facing are basically 2:

1) how can i search for a string in the sqlite databse and be sure that it is the same sentence with just a different number?

2) how can i generate the new sentence witht he correct number?

it has to be quick because a typical file to translate contains 5000 sentences and the database contains 10000 or more.

The language is VB.Net. all the code that does the searching is already made. what is still needed and i have no clue where to start is the code that searches for the same string with different numbers. a generic code would be ok, i can then adapt it to my code.

Thanks

Comment: [Sand Witches](http://aesobolwillowshade.files.wordpress.com/2012/08/sand-witches.jpg)

Comment: yeah exactly those.. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searches with wildcards can be done either with `LIKE`:

```sql
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Text LIKE 'I like to eat % sandwitches every % days'
```

or `GLOB` (case sensitive):

```sql
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Text GLOB 'I like to eat * sandwitches every * days'
```

However, such searches cannot use indexes.

You could use [full-text search](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html) tables instead.
`MATCH` does not support wildcards, but you could use the `NEAR` operator to search for adjacent sentence parts:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE Text MATCH '"I like to eat" NEAR/1 "sandwitches every" NEAR/1 days'
```

But `NEAR` does not regard the order, so this would also match a sentence like `I like to eat days sandwitches every`; you would have to check the returned string afterwards.

Comment: thanks for your answer! would it be a option to replace all numbers int eh string with a "_"? that should return any string that has any character in place of the _.. but how would i then correct the string?

Comment: `_` works only with `LIKE`, and is not any more efficient than `%`.